# Combining data from 2 tables when they don't have same keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example of the data I am talking about:

```
tbl1                                      tbl2
====================================     ====================================  
| id | id_name | purchased | count |     | id | date                | count |
====================================     ====================================
|  1 |  id1    | true      | 100   |     |  1 | 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | 50    |
|  2 |  id2    | false     | 40    |     |  1 | 2018-03-02 00:00:00 | 30    |
|  3 |  id3    | false     | 60    |     |  1 | 2018-03-03 00:00:00 | 25    |
|  4 |  id4    | false     | 100   |     ====================================
====================================
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the sum of 'count' in tbl1 but where 'purchased' = true I want to update that count with a sum of 'count' in tbl2 beyond a specific date: '2018-03-02'.

I've tried doing a combination of left joins and case whens, but because tbl2 doesn't have exact matching 'id' values my query is only outputting count values for id = 1.

Any help here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: apologies, to clarify this is MySQL and I’m not trying to update the actual table. I just want to pull the data for tbl1 and have the count data updated in that data output.

Comment: What is the expected output? Also which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You have only id = 1 in tbl2 so it's only giving output for id = 1

Comment: So, I do not fully understand in which table you'd like to update which count.
You want to all counts of tbl1 or in tbl2 ? Or you just want to get some kind of combined result? I sense you may need a `group by id` statement somewhere, but still try to give us more detailes about the result

Comment: I'm using MySQL. My expected output is basically tbl1 as is, but for purchased = true I want to update that count for that id with the sum of the counts in tbl2 beyond a certain date. Please let me know if that helped clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
update t tbl2
join select id,sum(`count`) as totalcnt from tbl1 where purchased=true group by id)t1 
on t.id=t1.id 
set t.`count`=totalcnt
where date>'2018-03-02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works

Select (Select count(id) from tbl1 where purchased=true)(Select count(count) from tbl2 where date >= "2018-03-03") as "total_count" from tbl1 , tbl2;